# How to receive multiple incoming calls in same browser device at the same time?

Tags: twilio

Currently we are getting incoming call in Twilio Javascript client device using the code below

```
Device.on('incoming', function(incomingCall) {
    console.log(incomingCall)
    incomingCall.accept();
});
```

We need to receive a second incoming call in the same device simultaneously, after answering the first call ( That is, when the first call is in progress )

We are able to receive the second call only if the first one is in ringing state, We have to find a solution to receive the second call while the first one is in progress

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the Device options you need to set `allowIncomingWhileBusy` to `true`. Then when the Device receives an incoming call while there is already an active call, it will fire the `incoming` event.

Check out more detail in the [Device Options documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#deviceoptions).